# Form with attachment to a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have been asked if this is possible in sharepoint, I would think it is but can't think of a way. I am starting to think that I need to do a developer course lol.

The request.

Have a form to fill out required fields,  then have a standard template in excel to upload to this form that will have parts on it.

This attachment will need to go in a list with the contents. 
I know I can manually upload an excel to create a new list. Is it possible to do this in a form?

Once the form is submitted an approval process is started.

Once approved,  I was thinking maybe having that new list that was created be merged with a master list.

I have tried this in Infopath 2013. The server we are running is SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.

I will keep digging but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.